# How to create conditional coloring for matplotlib table values?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I add conditional coloring to this table?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[16, 15, 14, 16],
                   'B': [3, -2, 5, 0],
                   'C': [200000, 3, 6, 800000],
                   'D': [51, -6, 3, 2]}) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
the_table = ax.table(cellText = df.values, colLabels = df.columns, loc='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

How do I add conditional coloring to the table where column A and column D values are greater than or equal to 15, the cells are red; else they're green. If column B and column C values are greater than or equal to 5, the cells are red; else they're green. This is what it should look like: 
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this kind of information be found in the documentation? As an aside, if you're using a more recent version of Pandas, you can replace `cellText=df.values.tolist()` with `cellText=df.to_numpy()`, otherwise just use `cellText=df.values`. Also, `colLabels=df.columns.tolist()` -> `colLabels=df.columns`.

Comment: @AMC I can't find anything that addresses conditional formatting. I'm only seeing `cellColours` be used for heatmap shading, or manual cell coloring. And thank you, I'll make those changes you've suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a list of lists and feed it to cellColours. Make sure that the list of lists contains as many lists as you have rows in the data frame and each of the lists within the list of lists contains as many strings as you have columns in the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[16, 15, 14, 16],
                   'B': [3, -2, 5, 0],
                   'C': [200000, 3, 6, 800000],
                   'D': [51, -6, 3, 2]}) 

colors = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    colors_in_column = ["g", "g", "g", "g"]
    if row["A"]>=15:
        colors_in_column[0] = "r"
    if row["B"]>=5:
        colors_in_column[1] = "r"
    if row["C"]>5:
        colors_in_column[2] = "r"        
    if row["D"]>=15:
        colors_in_column[3] = "r"
    colors.append(colors_in_column)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
the_table = ax.table(cellText = df.values, colLabels = df.columns, loc='center', cellColours=colors)
plt.show()
```